# Kivy Launcher: No puedo crear el directorio /storage/emulated/0/kivy

Tags: android, python, app, programación-móvil, kivy

Para lanzar una aplicación en Kivy Launcher me pone:

*No projects are available to launch. Please place a project into /storage/emulated/0/kivy and restart this application. Press the back button to exit*

Entonces busco ese directorio con el ES File Explorer, pero solo me aparece /storage/emulated. Trato de crear una carpeta llamada "0" pero me sale un mensaje: *Operación fallida!Use un nombre diferente*. Entonces trato de usar un nombre diferente, "prueba" y me pone: *Disculpe, Operación Fallida*

¿Por qué android no me deja crear carpetas en el directorio storage/emulated? ¿Hay alguna manera de que pueda crear las carpetas que necesito?

Dispositivo: Galaxy Tab A

Versión de Android: Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow)

Comment: No soy experto en Android pero creo recordar que /storage/emulated/ realmente no existe (es un link simbólico). ¿Puedes acceder al directorio físico en  `/sdcard` y crear carpetas aquí? ¿Te deja hacerlo desde el pc? añade la version de Android que usas por si tiene algo que ver. Realmente Kivy Laucher debería haber creado la carpeta `kivy` dentro `/sdcard` ya que vienen unos cuantas apps de ejemplo, a no ser que sea un tema de permisos y no deje crear carpetas ni a ti ni al Laucher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En principio esto debería funcionar:

- Conectas el teléfono al PC.
- Te vas a Equipo y abres tu equipo Android.
- Entras en el almacenamiento interno, si no tienes memoria externa solo aparecerá este dispositivo.
- En la raiz del almacenamiento interno creas la carpeta `kivy`.
- Dentro de esta carpeta metes las carpetas de tus apps.

Mirate este [vídeo de youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVuvcvZ8VSA) donde aparece la secuencia explicada a ver si puedes resolver el problema.